# How to make a column extend to push the columns below it over

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't think I asked this as clearly as I could for easy searching, but here goes:

How can I make a bootstrap column extend to a larger height so that when the columns wrap around, they get offset by it even if it's not tall enough to cause that normally.

Essentially, how do I make the `bottom` panel in this bootply stay centered in both cases?
http://www.bootply.com/FCgrUtGuQ0

My `left` panel will be of variable length, which means that if I use a `col-x-offset-x` it will get pushed over further if the `left` panel extends below `middle`.

If I add the `bottom` panel to a new row then it will have whitespace above it if the panel `left` is longer than `middle`.

I tried the negative margin trick without success. It lets you change the background colour which those examples all used, but it doesn't seem to cause the floated panels to shift right.

I need this layout to behave differently at smaller screen sizes, so I can't just put the `middle` and `bottom` in the same `col-x-6` as this is actually my `lg` layout, and at `sm` I need it to act with `left` at the top in a row, `middle` and `right` as two columns in the second row, and `bottom` as a third row.

Negative margin trick:

```
.row {
  overflow:hidden;
}

#extend-down {
    padding-bottom: 10000px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't answering my own question directly, as it doesn't explain how to expand the column height to make the repositioning happen properly, and it's not generic to all column sizes and arrangements.

But in my exact case this arrangement of columns and rows case can be solved with two master columns and then separating the contents of the second, where 3-6-3 columns can easily be made to be 3-9(4-8) columns which maintain the same 3-6-3 spacing.

http://www.bootply.com/UTq2klEuCG

By putting the `middle`, `right`, and `bottom` in the second column then letting those wrap around naturally seems to handle all my cases with this specific layout.

So I went from

```
col-x-3
col-x-6
col-x-3
col-x-6
```

to

```
col-x-3
col-x-9
{
    col-x-8
    col-x-4
    col-x-8
}
```

This isn't ideal, as a 2-8-2 arrangement might be best at a large screen size, but the math doesn't work to easily create a subset within the `col-x-10` that would need that follows the same spacing as a 2-8-2.